# Shift key on keyboard works only sometimes

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop, shift

So my shift keys randomly stopped working one day, and now they go between working and not working. I have to press down hard for the key to work, usually and sometimes they don't. Often running my hands over other keys lets them work for a bit but not always. Interesting thing is the right hand side key works a bit more often than left hand side one (left side one NEVER works with letter `t`). I'm not sure what could possibly be wrong, very certain it's a keyboard issue however.

How do I fix it or find what exactly this problem is?

Comment: Great story... what's your question? :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 How to fix it? Or how to diagnose what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you tried to use another one keyboard?

Comment: @duDE No I don't have any around presently.

Comment: You need to do it, dude. Ask your friendly neighbor :)

Comment: @duDE Okay. Nice pun btw.

Comment: Do you have a cat?  How old is the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ubuntu the remedies mentioned in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742762/keys-malfunctioning-ctrl-and-shift-seem-to-be-pressed-when-they-arent-or-don) may be worth a try:

I experienced very similar issues with my HP Spectre x360. Intermittent failure of the Shift keys, which strangely enough was also sensitive to the tilt angle of the keyboard. The issue mimics a hardware failure perfectly, only tell that this is a software issue is the fact that both Shifts keys are affected.

Ultimately the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT settings in the */etc/default/grub* that seems to have taken care of the problem are:

```
i8042.direct=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1 i8042.nopnp=1
```

The complete statement in this file is now:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.direct=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1 i8042.nopnp=1"
```

Setting only i8042.dumbkbd did not work in my case.

Note, you will have to run *update-grub* for these settings to take effect.